# Jquery check if image is selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a grid of images which is generated by PHP as HTML. When an image is clicked, I want to be able to mark is as clicked, and do a few things like add it to an array of clickedArray[], change some HTML to show clickedArray.length, and make an image which is over the top of it appear. And if it's clicked again, basically do the opposite. I have this code here:

```
$("img").click(function() { $(this).attr("selected", "true"); });
```

Though, I can't give my images an `id=` because it seems to break the HTML and the image won't appear, so I think that will affect this whole thing. This is the HTML for that if it helps at all:

```
<img src= '$link[Image_Link] . /133x100' title='$row[Item_Name]' alt='$just_name' onClick='addValue(". $credit_value .")' border=0 style='position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;'/>
```

I want to post more of the jquery code I have tried but I know it's not right. What I want it to do is every time the image is clicked, change it's selected attribute from true<->false, add or remove it from clickArray, and change a HTML element, I'm not sure how to go about it though.

Comment: how image can be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/mbyc6gr0/)

You can use a data attribute to mark the image as selected. You can also add a class to visually show that it is selected.

```
 $('img').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).data('selected', false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).data('selected', true);
    }
});
```

You can declare an array, and add items to it by iterating through a collection with a jquery selector:

```
var selectedImageArray = [];
$('img').each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('selected')) {
        selectedImageArray.push(this.id);
    }
});
```

You can get the selectedImageArray length using `.length` and output it to an html element such as a span using `.text()` like this:

```
<span id="selectedItemsSpan">Selected Items:</span>

<script>
    $('#selectedItemsSpan').text('You have selected the following ' + selectedImageArray.length + ' items.');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use the data attribute instead of selected="true" (https://api.jquery.com/data/)

i.e.

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $(this).data('selected',true);
}
```